# Getting a footer to stay at bottom of WINDOW (not page) & not overlap content

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there's a *CSS solution* for this issue.

The idea is to have a footer that:
1. Stays put at the bottom of the **window**, not the page (i.e. if the content is bigger than the window - whatever size that window is - the footer is **always visible** and stuck to the bottom of the browser window, not stuck underneath all the content out of sight)

*BUT CRUCIALLY **ALSO***

2. **Doesn't overlap content** when additional content is added to the page (i.e. the content can't scroll behind it)

A good example to think about this is a chat app where you enter your message at the bottom and you want your message to appear directly above that message input box. Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8d08200q/ (code below because stackoverflow enforces it).

Currently the jsfiddle resolves the first issue but not the second (content goes behind the message input box).
The standard [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/) resolves the second issue but if the content is bigger than the window, the message input box disappears.

Any ideas for a **CSS-only solution** compatible with IE9+ (not involving javascript to restrain the body to the browser window size)?

The most relevant CSS is:

```
 body { 
  font: 1.5em Helvetica, Arial; 
  height: 100%; 
  padding-bottom: 2.5em;}


form {
  background: #2c3e50;
  padding: 3px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5em; }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what scrolling behavior you want for your content when it is taller than the window. I think of three :

1. A scrollbar appears to scroll *only* the content (the footer always stay below the content). When you add new content, it is added at the end but you have to manually scroll down to get it into view.
2. You always want to see the bottom of the content. When new content is added, you want it to "push up" the previous content. The new content will then be always just above the footer. But, in this scenario, you do not have a scrollbar to see the any content that was pushed up over the window.
3. Same as number 2, but, in this scenario, you want scrollbars to be able to see all the previous content.

The reason why I put number 2 and 3 is because you can do number 2 with CSS only while you will need JavaScript for number 3.

**First, number 1:**

If your content is element `.main-content` and your footer is element `.footer`, then the solution is mainly around this CSS :

```
.main-content {
  height: 85vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 15vh;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

See a more complete example here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGLLXz

**Number 2:**

You would mainly change the CSS of `.main-content` to this :

```
.main-content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15vh;
}
```

Complete example here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdBBVM

**Number 3:**

The CSS would be the same as number 1, but you would add a JavaScript function that will scrolldown to the bottom `.main-content` everytime new content is added.

See this example : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVBBvd

Comment: What a fantastic answer, thank you! Do you know of a way to have number 2 (it's exactly what I wanted with the new content always showing up just above the footer without having to scroll to it), but also allowing users to scroll up to previous content? Big ask!

Comment: It might not do *everything* I need it to but this definitely answers the question I asked, so thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider having 2 sections - one for the page content and one for the footer. Section one has scrollable content and stays in place. The footer wont have to move anywhere nor the page, just the content of the first section

Comment: I tried that by adding a div named `chat-container` around the messages content and styling it as `.chat-container{
    height: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}` but the content still hides behind the message input box :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> DEmpo</title>
    <style>
    .container {
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #container_1 {
        padding-bottom: 200px
    }
    
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background: red;
        height: 200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="container_1">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate esse ab quibusdam nostrum aperiam officiis perspiciatis, odit asperiores, eius voluptatibus hic enim praesentium! Quod incidunt, doloremque nostrum porro ducimus cupiditate? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate esse ab quibusdam nostrum aperiam officiis perspiciatis, odit asperiores, eius voluptatibus hic enim praesentium! Quod incidunt, doloremque nostrum porro ducimus cupiditate? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate esse ab quibusdam nostrum aperiam officiis perspiciatis, odit asperiores, eius voluptatibus hic enim praesentium! Quod incidunt, doloremque nostrum porro ducimus cupiditate? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate esse ab quibusdam nostrum aperiam officiis perspiciatis, odit asperiores, eius voluptatibus hic enim praesentium! Quod incidunt, doloremque nostrum porro ducimus cupiditate? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate esse ab quibusdam nostrum aperiam officiis perspiciatis, odit asperiores, eius voluptatibus hic enim praesentium! Quod incidunt, doloremque nostrum porro ducimus cupiditate?
            </p>
            <footer>kdfgdgkk</footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```